# UserForm to Search for, Cut, and Paste info onto new Sheet with Additional Info

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I have two UserForms in my Worksheet, one to add clients and one to remove. The "Add Client" works perfect, however the "Remove Client" does not. I have used Breakpoints to see where my code is going wrong and what seems to be happening is it skips from "Private Sub OkButton2_Click()" to "On Error GoTo Err_Execute" and from "If Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = DCNameTextBox1.Value Then" all the way down to "End If"

I want the VBA upon the user clicking Okay to search for what was input in the Name box, cut that row from A to F(deleting the entire row), paste the info in the next empty row in sheet 2 and add the additional info the user put into the user form. I have looked at a lot of different codes and questions and none of them seem to quite do what I want.

```
Private Sub OkButton2_Click()

    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim LSearchRow As Integer
    Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

   On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   'Start search in row 3
   LSearchRow = 3

   'Start copying data to row 3 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
   LCopyToRow = 3

   While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

      'If value in column A = "Client Name", copy entire row to Sheet2
      If Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = DCNameTextBox1.Value Then

         'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
         Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & "A:F" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
         Selection.Copy

         'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
         Sheets("Sheet2").Select
         Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & "A:F" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
        'Add/Transfer Discharge info
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = DCDateTextBox.Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = DispoTextBox.Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = ReasonTextBox.Value

         'Move counter to next row
         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

         'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
         Sheets("Sheet1").Select


      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

   Wend

   'Position on cell A3
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Range("A3").Select

   MsgBox "Client has been moved to Discharge list."

   Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Comment: `Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & "A:F" & CStr(LSearchRow))` --> error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Range.Find` is a little more efficient.

```
Private Sub OkButton2_Click()
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Source = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set Target = Source.Find(What:=DCNameTextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not Target Is Nothing Then
        'Reference the next enmpty row on Sheet2
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                '.Range("A1:F1") is relative to the row of it's parent range
                .Range("A1:F1").Value = Target.Range("A1:F1").Value
                .Range("H1:J1").Value = Array(DCDateTextBox.Value, DispoTextBox.Value, ReasonTextBox.Value)

                Set Source = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            End With
        End With
        Target.Range("A1:F1").Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        MsgBox "Client has been moved to Discharge list."
    Else
        MsgBox "Client not found", vbInformation, "No Data"
    End If

    Range("A3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG Thank you! So much easier. Made a couple minor tweaks (added "EntireRow" to delete command, G1:I1) but otherwise perfect.